# AngularJS smart-table / Select rows - single

Tags: angularjs, smart-table

i need to make selectable table rows in smart-table

> st-select-row="row" st-select-mode="single"

But how can I modify that so one time selectable row stays selected until the next row will be clicked ? I have some links (target will be open in new window) and when they are clicked I get row selected and next time unselected...

Any hints ?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution for my problem. I've modified "select" function from smart-table by adding additional condition (marked bellow as "new condition").
Maybe it will be useful for someone :)

```
    if (mode === 'single') {
      if (lastSelected !== row) {  // new condition
        row.isSelected = row.isSelected !== true;
        if (lastSelected) {
          lastSelected.isSelected = false;
        }
        lastSelected = row.isSelected === true ? row : undefined;
      }
    } else {
      rows[index].isSelected = !rows[index].isSelected;
    }
```